# For given directory, how to check which files has specific permission flag in the group part?

Tags: permissions, group

I have a directory and i want to list all files that has permissions for writing in their group part, no matter to which group they belong.

Also, how it can be done for the whole filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` with the `-perm` predicate. From [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1posix.html) (POSIX):

```
-perm [-]mode

      The mode argument is used to represent file mode bits. It  shall
      be identical in format to the symbolic_mode operand described in
      chmod() , and shall be interpreted  as  follows.   To  start,  a
      template shall be assumed with all file mode bits cleared. An op
      symbol of '+'  shall  set  the  appropriate  mode  bits  in  the
      template;  '-'  shall  clear the appropriate bits; '=' shall set
      the appropriate mode bits, without regard  to  the  contents  of
      process' file mode creation mask. The op symbol of '-' cannot be
      the first character of mode;  this  avoids  ambiguity  with  the
      optional leading hyphen. Since the initial mode is all bits off,
      there are not any symbolic modes that need to  use  '-'  as  the
      first character.

If  the  hyphen is omitted, the primary shall evaluate as true when the
file permission bits exactly match the value of the resulting template.

Otherwise, if mode is prefixed by a hyphen, the primary shall  evaluate
as  true  if at least all the bits in the resulting template are set in
the file permission bits.
```

Therefore, you can try:

```
find /some/path/ -type f -perm -g=w
```

`-type f` tests for regular files. For the whole filesystem, replace `/some/path` with `/`.